# How to Store decoded json data into variables and insert them in to mysql table

Tags: php, android, json

Hi In my android application Iam retrieving the data from sqlite and now by using JSON i want to store that data into mysql table.Please help me to achieve this

I'm not getting how to store all the values in a table only single row is inserting each time I try to insert.

This is the code.

```
<?php

error_reporting(0);

include_once 'db_conn.php';  //Include the database connection strings


$received_json = $_POST["sparesJSON"];

if (get_magic_quotes_gpc())

{
    $received_json = stripslashes($received_json);
}

$received_json = json_decode($received_json);

//catch variable

$item_name = $received_json[0]->item_name;

$quantity = $received_json[0]->quantity;

$total_price = $received_json[0]->total_price;

$cycle_id = $received_json[0]->cycle_id;

$date = $received_json[0]->date;

for($i=0;i<count($received_json;i++)
{


            $insert_spares = "insert into spares_items (item_name, quantity, total_price,    cycle_id, date) values (\"$item_name\", \"$quantity\", \"$total_price\", \"$cycle_id\", \"$date\")";

            mysql_query($insert_spares);
}

//encode result array in json

echo json_encode($cycle_id);


//send this as an response to the Android
?>
```

Comment: Please, [don't use `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php), They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://us1.php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://us1.php.net/mysqli). You will also want to [Prevent SQL Injection!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$received_json = json_decode($received_json);



for($i=0;$i<count($received_json);$i++)
{


    $item_name = $received_json[$i]->item_name;

    $quantity = $received_json[$i]->quantity;

    $total_price = $received_json[$i]->total_price;

    $cycle_id = $received_json[$i]->cycle_id;

    $date = $received_json[$i]->date;    
    $insert_spares = "insert into spares_items (item_name, quantity, total_price,    cycle_id, date) values (\"$item_name\", \"$quantity\", \"$total_price\", \"$cycle_id\", \"$date\")";

    mysql_query($insert_spares);
}
```

Comment: can i know what should be the response also at the end?

Comment: Gather all $cycle_id values into an array. Output them after the loop.

Comment: actually in my situation there is no need of gather or storing them.what i need is just compose json data from sqlite and store them is mysql thats it.Now can i skip the response...?

Comment: can I also know how to eliminate duplicate values while inserting into table...?

Comment: For the first one: yes, you can skip the response if you don't need it on the client-side.

For the second one: depends on which values will be duplicated. You can maintain an array that tracks all the values seen so far and check against it before inserting a new row.

Comment: can you please help me with an example..?since I'm new to php Iam unable to get this

Comment: Added another answer. Compare this against the first answer and you'll see how to do it :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
$received_json = json_decode($received_json);

$inserted_names = array();

for($i=0;$i<count($received_json);$i++)
{


    $item_name = $received_json[$i]->item_name;
    // if we have already inserted this name, don't insert again
    if (in_array($item_name, $inserted_names)) {
        continue;
    }

    $quantity = $received_json[$i]->quantity;

    $total_price = $received_json[$i]->total_price;

    $cycle_id = $received_json[$i]->cycle_id;

    $date = $received_json[$i]->date;    
    $insert_spares = "insert into spares_items (item_name, quantity, total_price,    cycle_id, date) values (\"$item_name\", \"$quantity\", \"$total_price\", \"$cycle_id\", \"$date\")";

    mysql_query($insert_spares);
    // save item name to list of names already inserted
    array_push($inserted_names, $item_name);
}
```